# Existence of absolutely continuous measures

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

I am curious about the following:

Given an arbitrary signed or complex measure $\nu$, does there always exist a (nontrivial) positive measure $\mu$ such that $\nu \ll \mu$?

I suspect the answer is yes (at least for $\sigma$-finite $\nu$), and I have tried to think about somehow using the Radon-Nikodym theorem, but as of yet I have no good line of reasoning which would constitute an answer.

Thanks in advance for the help,

Comment: What counts as nontrivial? We always have $\nu \ll \lvert\nu\rvert$.

Comment: That's enough for me.  Can't believe I didn't think of that.  Thank you

Comment: Perhaps there are more interesting answers out there, but I just needed justification for a step in a proof I am reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $|\mu|$. Where:

$|\mu|(E)=\sup_{\cup E_n=E\,\,\&\,\,E_i\cap E_j=\varnothing}\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\mu(E_n)|$

In fact
$$
d\mu=h\,d|\mu|
$$
where $|h|=1$ $\mu-$a.e.

Comment: Great.  Thank you for the help.